# declare a template vector member in a class without template the class?

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I have some class that should be populated with values,
but I don't know the type of values.

To clarify, each vector in a class instance is populated with the same value types,
But one instance of SomeClass can have `vector<int>` and another `vector<string>` and so on.

How can I declare the vector as template, but not template the class itself?

```
template<typename T>
struct tvector {
     typedef std::vector< std::vector<T> > type;
};

class SomeClass {
  public:
      int _someField;                                   
      tvector<T> _fieldValues;  // this line fails to compile
};
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't do it: you have to make `SomeClass` a template as well. Why do you want to do that? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: the compiler cannnot determine how much size is your `tvector<T>`, and what type is it.

Comment: Do you perhaps need `std::variant`? It's not clear exactly what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different ways to shear this beast. It mostly depends on how you want to access this vector and how you determine its exact type at runtime.

### std::variant

A variant can store a set of predetermined types. It's effective but also cumbersome if you have many different types because you have to funnel every access through some type checking.

```
class SomeClass {
public:
    using variant_type = std::variant<
          std::vector<int>, std::vector<double> >;
    int _someField;
    variant_type _fieldValues;

    void print(std::ostream& stream) const
    {
        switch(_fieldValues.index()) {
        case 0:
            for(int i: std::get<0>(_fieldValues))
                stream << i << ' ';
            break;
        case 1:
            for(double i: std::get<1>(_fieldValues))
                stream << i << ' ';
            break;
        default: break;
        }
    }
};
```

### std::any

Any can hold literally any type. Improves extendability but makes working with the values hard.

```
class SomeClass {
public:
    int _someField;
    std::any _fieldValues;

    void print(std::ostream& stream) const
    {
        if(_fieldValues.type() == typeid(std::vector<int>))
            for(int i: std::any_cast<std::vector<int>>(_fieldValues))
                stream << i << ' ';
        else if(_fieldValues.type() == typeid(std::vector<double>))
            for(double i: std::any_cast<std::vector<double>>(_fieldValues))
                stream << i << ' ';
        else
            throw std::runtime_error("Not implemented");
    }
};
```

### Subclassing

The most elegant way (IMHO) is to use a templated subclass. Something like this:

```
class SomeClass {
public:
    int _someField;
    virtual ~SomeClass() = default;
    virtual void print(std::ostream& stream) const = 0;
};
template<class T>
SomeClassT: public SomeClass
{
    std::vector<T> _fieldValues;
public:
    virtual void print(std::ostream& stream) const
    {
        for(const T& i: _fieldValues)
            stream << i << ' ';
    }
};
```

Or if you don't want to expose that part, make it a private member.

```
class SomeClassHelper {
public:
    virtual ~SomeClassHelper() = default;
    virtual void print(std::ostream& stream) const = 0;
};

template<class T>
SomeClassHelperT: public SomeClassHelper
{
    std::vector<T> _fieldValues;
public:
    virtual void print(std::ostream& stream) const
    {
        for(const T& i: _fieldValues)
            stream << i << ' ';
    }
};
class SomeClass {
public:
    int _someField;
private:
    std::unique_ptr<SomeClassHelper> helper;
public:
    void print(std::ostream& stream) const
    { return helper->print(stream); }
};
```